# Setting up Linux gcc toolchain/compiler on eclipse using the Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: eclipse, windows, ubuntu, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was wondering if the Windows Subsystem for Linux enables me to select its Linux GCC compiler when creating a new C++ project in Eclipse when using Windows 10? If it is, I was wondering how I would go about setting it up. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is *Ubuntu subsystem for Windows*?

Comment: I mixed the name up, as it is oficially called "Windows Subsystem for Linux". Essentially it is a compatibility layer for running Linux binary executables natively on Windows 10

Comment: You could add a build tool that is a batch file that calls bash to do your make, e.g. batch contains `bash -c "make"` or even just a shortcut that points at that.... or just running it in the eclipse terminal may work even.

Comment: You might find my response here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43973126/1345870 relevant...

Comment: Yes that is certainly something I can work with!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Eclipse inside the Windows Subsystem for Linux? That's the simplest way I can think of (provided Eclipse works, I can see the JVM being a problem).

You'll need an X11 server for Windows. I use https://github.com/ArcticaProject/vcxsrv to run a terminal emulator called Sakura, as well as my favorite text editor.

Answer (score 0):

There's a severe flaw in using the Xserver approach if you happen to be using a VPN that also blocks network interfaces as some do for working from home. Basically, while the VPN is connected the internal interface used for WSL to talk to the XServer is blocked. WSL1 didn't have this issue, WSL2 does.